# Softmax computation in Transformers

Tags: natural-language, softmax, transformers

In word embedding model `word2vec`, computation of softmax is expensive process and hence we use many alternative as provided [here](https://ruder.io/word-embeddings-softmax/#:%7E:text=The%20softmax%20layer%20is%20a,make%20the%20computation%20more%20efficient.). Prominently, `hierarchical softmax` and `negative sampling` are used in such case.

Now, while working with `transformer` model such as `BERT` requires us to compute softmax over vocabulary ([you may check here](https://towardsdatascience.com/breaking-bert-down-430461f60efb)). This make me think about the following,

Q. Why `transformers` doesn't use softmax approximation? or do they use it?